# What is the instantaneous P&L of a Variance Swap?

Tags: volatility, implied-volatility, swaps, variance, replication

What is the instantaneous P&L of a variance swap.

Is it $(\sigma^{2}_{t}-\sigma^{2}_{implied})dt$?

Comment: Your question would benefit from a link or a short reminder of how a variance swap works, possibly including formulas in the post and indication how you got to your solution.

Comment: Perhaps he means something like the instantaneous credit risk of a variance swap?

Answer (score 1):

A variance swap has a set of fixing times, and the volatility between those times has no specified effect.  Therefore you end up wanting to apply a model.  For a model-free approximation, though, your formula works up to a constant.

Answer (score 1):

definition of a variance swap is

$ \int^{T+\Delta}_T \mathbb{E}_t[v_s] ds $

where $v_s$ is the variance and $\mathbb{E}_t[v_s]$ is the expectation of the variance of time s at time t.

therefore, pnl is:
$ (\int^{T+\Delta}_T \mathbb{E}_t[v_s] ds - \int^{T+\Delta}_{T} \mathbb{E}_{t-\delta}[v_s] ds)*d\delta $